# html textarea gets very slow

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I've got a simple webpage that prints some data into a textarea that it gets from a remote device but I've noticed that when it gets too big it gets very slow to update.
It seems to me that everytime I send new data the whole thing is rebuilt on the browser memory or something, even though that I'm just appending to the old data.

Is there any simple way to overcome this?
You can easily notice what I'm describing by running the simple code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload='load()'>

<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>

<script>
function load() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
    var text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    var a, i;

    for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        textarea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        }
    alert(a);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to input 680,000 letters into a `textarea`?

Comment: Manipulating the DOM is not the fastest thing, so creating textnodes 10,000 times in nested loops isn't going to be fast. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: well maybe this wasn't the best example but my data will be coming through a websocket from a webserver connected to a serial comms monitoring device. 680Kb of serial data doesn't seem like a lot to me..

Comment: *`even though that I'm just appending to the old data.`*  JS strings do not append. They are immutable - that is, concatenation is creating a whole new string every time.

Comment: @sorh Thanks for the details. I would add it into an array with a max number of messages to display, and as you add new ones, you `shift` the old ones out. Unless of course you really need to display all the incoming messages, then you just have to deal with the slowness.

Comment: many thanks for your comments guys. I'll just limit the amount of messages to display then.